# How to change Firebird default port in linux?

Tags: linux, opensuse, firebird

I'm trying to change firebird (2.5.1) default port from 3050 to 3051 on OpenSuse 11.4

So I installed firebird (`install.sh`) and in `/opt/firebird/firebird.conf` I uncommented and changed `RemoteServicePort` to `3051`, reboot the server but the service is still running on 3050.

Do I forgot something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit /etc/services end set

```
gds_db          3051/tcp                        # InterBase server
gds_db          3051/udp
```

Check this link [Multiple Firebird Servers on Ubuntu](http://www.gefoo.org/generalfoo/2011/02/21/multiple-firebird-servers-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Thanks - that was it :-)

The service register in `/scripts/postinstall.sh` so it can be edited before install.